# Copy data with new IDs

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is there any way to COPY some rows into same table with new IDs?
My table is like this:

```
ID | data
 1 | SOMETHING
 2 | SOMETHING
 3 | SOMETHING
```

I have old IDs: `'{1,513,3,4,5}'`, and new ones: `'{1338,7,512,9,10}'` and I need to add row 1338 with data from row 1, 7 <= 513 etc. Like `old[0] = new[0]`.

Currently I am using a loop:

```
SELECT old_ids INTO oIds FROM vars_table WHERE sid = id;
FOR i IN 0..array_length(new_ids, 1) LOOP
  INSERT INTO ids(ID, data)
    SELECT new_ids[i], data
    FROM ids
    WHERE id = oIds[i]
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ids WHERE id = new_ids[i]);
END LOOP;
```

Is there better way to do this? Maybe in 1 query?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop:

```
insert into the_table (id, data)
select id + 5, data
from the_table;
```

However the above requires you to know how many rows there are in the table. To take the current number of rows into account you can do:

```
insert into the_table (id, data)
select id + (select max(id) from the_table), data
from the_table;
```

#### Attention: the above is *NOT* safe in a multi-user environment. It should only be used if you are the only one doing this.

---

The best way to deal with this kind of data duplication is to define the `ID` column as `serial` and let Postgres deal with creating new values:

```
create table the_table (id serial not null, data text);
```

The initial data would then be inserted like this:

```
insert into the_table (data)
values ('foo'), ('bar'), ('foobar');
```

Duplicating the data is then as easy as:

```
insert into the_table (data)
select data 
from the_data;
```

Comment: Always horse :D I have updated my question, IDs is not serial.

Comment: @ShamilYakupov I do understand that your `ID` is not a serial - but if you need copy data like that very often, *changing* it to a serial makes your life a **lot** easier.

Comment: I can't do this. This IDs is not from my system.